# Python Module Level Constants

Tags: python, module, python-2.7, package

I am creating my first rather complex module, and like the wx module, I wish to provide a variety of constants to ease the programmers task of setting styles.

assuming the following directory structure:

```
Module
   +-__init__py
   +- Frame.py
```

and the contents of **init**.py

```
__ALL__=["Frame.py"]
FRAME_DEFAULT_SIZE = (640, 480)
FRAME_DEFAULT_TITLE = "Some Simple Title"
```

then in Frame.py

```
class Frame(object)
    """Some docstrings go here
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=-1,title=HOW DO I REFERENCE MY CONSTANT,
                 size = HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS CONSTANT):
        etc ...
```

If I were to import my module for use in a piece of program code the constants would be available as Module.FRAME_DEFAULT_SIZE, and Module.FRAME_DEFAULT_TITLE respectively.

But how do i reference them as part of a class definition which is supposed to be in the modules name-space, when they are defined in a separate file?

I realize that constants (if named well and used well) should apply only to a parent class and it's children, so I could instantiate them in the Frame.py file.  But how does one do it this way?

Any help appreciated here.

Comment: Why are the constants in `__init__.py`? Put them in `Frame.py`

Comment: lol.  I plan on it, but I want to know how to do it this way as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `Module` and access it off that. That part doesn't change just because you're in a submodule.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. The code ( as i have it set up in the example) creates a namespace "Module" with nothing in it except some constants.  And to usilize those constants in Module.Frame, I would actually need to import Module into Frame.  Obviosly not a good idea due to circular dependancy issues, but do I understand it right?

Comment: Python doesn't have any problems with circular dependencies. What it can't do is use a name that doesn't exist yet. As long as you don't try to instantiate a `Module.Frame` before the constants in `Module` exist you won't have a problem with this.